# regex to match a number followed by spaces

Tags: java, regex

I'm looking to use reg-ex to split the following string

```
1 hi my name is John. 2 I live at house 32. 3 I see stars.
```

to

```
[hi my name is John,  I live at house 32. , I see stars]
```

Note that am trying to split on digit followed by a space

Comment: what's your programming language?

Comment: @SinaIravanian. Java. does it matter?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Split on `/(^|\b\s+)\d+\s+/g`.

Explanation:

- `(^|\b\s+)` *A collection of either `^` or `\b\s+`)*

  - `^` *Start of the string* OR
  - `\b\s+` *a [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)  followed by a space/tab repeated 1 or more times*
- `\d+` *A digit between 0 and 9 repeated 1 or more times* (so it'd match 1, 12, 123, etc.)
- `\s+` *A space/tab repeated 1 or more times*

**Edit**:

`(^|\.\s+)\d+\s+` might work better for you.

Comment: Add a \s+ after \d+, as white spaces after the digit was a requirement (as opposite to what comes before the digit!)

Comment: You can't repeat a word boundary. So the quantifier after `\b` is superfluous.

Comment: This expression is still not working. It is matching only on the first digit, because before 2 and 3 there is no word boundary followed by whitespace before. (I have no idea why you have this requirement.) [See it on Regexr](http://regexr.com?35605).

Comment: @stema You're right - it might be a better solution to use `(^|\.\s+)\d+\s+`.

Comment: Why all this? Just use `\d+ `? Or `\b\d+ ` if you want to be picky.

Comment: @Qtax Then `I used to live in house 32 right down the street` would match at `32`.

Comment: So? That's the requirement in question and what the OP wants. If you want to make sure the numbers increase from 1 to N then you can't evel solve this with regex.

Comment: @Qtax Logically when looking at the OP's question you can clearly see he's trying to turn a list `1 Foo. 2 Bar. 3 Foobar.` into the different list items splitted. SO isn't always about "doing it exactly like the OP requests" but rather give the OP a better idea of doing it. You wouldn't go on a PHP `mysql_*` question and not bother to suggest PDO or MySQLi would you?

Comment: And just so you know, your answer would also split on `32` in `I used to live in house 32 right down the street`. All the complexity you add is useless, and no better than `\b\d+ `.

Comment: @h2ooooooo, except that the link you posted is not [your answer](http://regexr.com?35616).

Comment: @QTax Hence the edit [17 minutes ago](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17020844/revisions). You are more than welcome to post your own answer, if you feel mine is not sufficient. Surely it'd be a better use of time rather than discussing how part of an old answer (that was accepted) is indeed not correct and the edit is not acceptable enough.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this will do: `[0-9]{1}[\ ]`

Comment: `[0-9]{1}` is equal to `[0-9]` and `[\ ]` is equal to `\ `

Comment: `[\ ]` is just a single space (unless `/x`/`(?x)` is used, then you need to escape it).

Answer (score 1):

Split on:

```
/\d+ /
```

Only the first match will be empty because it's the match just before the first number: `1`, so you gotta ignore that one.